# Subnetting on a Wireless Network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, home-networking

To reduce network congestion, is it at all useful to subnet your home **wireless** network?

Basically, I am having an issue with dropped connections and high latency on my network. We have about 12 devices, between our Rokus, Fire TVs, Apple TV devices, two laptops, a PC, and a couple phones and tablets. I have read that subnetting is useful for reducing network congestion because it breaks up broadcast domains (no source I have read has explicitly said that subnets break up broadcast domains, but that is what I have inferred), but would this actually reduce network congestion on a wireless network? It's my understanding that a wireless network is forced to broadcast its signals to everyone and that switching is only possible on a wired network (the wireless router can't really *choose* to send its signals in one direction). So even if the signals of other subnets were ignored by the hosts, they would still receive these, and then have to make the decision to ignore them, which will not reduce network congestion.

Am I right that there is no benefit to subnetting a wireless network to reduce latency?

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell: subnetting alone doesn't help one bit. As long as all those subnets are on the same channel they all arbitrate for the same, single medium.

There are optimizations that can be done though - mileage varies depending on the exact environment parameters. Channel optimization can help avoid overlapping channels with other nearby WLANs (see below). Better hardware with MIMO can increase single stream throughput somewhat and may free up some air time for other streams.

Don't use repeaters. Single-channel repeaters eat up twice the bandwidth of a direct connection. Where required, use separate, wired WAPs to increase reach.

To significantly increase throughput in a wireless network you need to utilize multiple channels. Neighboring channels are overlapping, so you need to space them apart at least 3 channels. Using the 5 GHz band in addition to the usual 2.4 GHz band also helps quite a lot as it's much less overcrowded.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is said multiple subnets break broadcast domains is because *usually* they're separated by a router – subnet A on interface eth1, subnet B on interface eth2, and so on. In other words, multiple subnets implies multiple physical links. (VLANs may also work.)

But merely having two subnets on the same "link" (whether Ethernet or Wi-Fi) will not do that. Broadcast packets on all subnets will still be broadcast at link-layer, and will reach all other subnets on the same link.

In short, yes, what you describe is correct. Subnets would only help if you had separate Wi-Fi networks on different channels.

---

That said,

> the wireless router can't really choose to send its signals in one direction

...is only *mostly* correct. Modern Wi-Fi access points do use various "beamforming" techniques (involving multiple antennas, as far as my limited knowledge goes); I don't think it results in an actual directional beam, but it *does* focus the signal in the exact spot where your device is. I imagine MU-MIMO also relies on similar features in order to talk to several devices at once. Corrections are welcome...

Comment: Beam forming , is constructive interference , no beam is formed, just areas of greater signal strength, calculated to coincide with the location of the client. So it's still omnidirectional